# Android - Create a background service for a video

Tags: android

I have an activity that creates a service, this service is responsible to play a video and allow to listen to the audio of the video even if the application is put in background. The problem is, how can I play the audio in the service and allow the application, when the activity is shown, to display the video inside the activity? I mean, when the application is in foreground I need the video shown, when it's in background I just need the audio, but without stopping and restarting the video.

I hope I made myself clear...

Thank you

Sebastiano

Answer (score 0):

to enable service:

```
try {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(thisActivity, AlarmReciever.class);
            Apps.sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(thisActivity, 2, intent1,
                    0);
            Apps.am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            long l = new Date().getTime();
            if (l < new Date().getTime()) {
                l += 100;
            }
            Apps.am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, l, 100, sender);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

add class AlarmReciver:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Play.check();
        // Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

add activity Play and create inside it method `check()`

```
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public static void check() {
ActivityManager am1 = (ActivityManager) thisActivity
                .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        String packageName = am1.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
                .getPackageName();
      if(packageName == "your app package name")
          {

          }
      else
       {
             //if video play; show it
             //else play audio
       }

    }
```

Last thing add permission to mainfest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
```